# Ошибки WordPress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-плагины, wp-plugin, wp-theme

Раньше был установлен **OSPanel** и **WordPress** 4 версии (и то, и то). Когда прилетело обновление на **WordPress** (это было недавно) я решил обновиться и скачал его. Но WordPress потребовал обновления **OSPanel**, что я в дальнейшем и сделал. И почему-то после обновление одного и другого, при копирование папки с темой в папку "**Wp-content**", в админ панели **WordPress** мне выбивает такие ошибки:

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at C:\OSPanel\domains\ancores.com\wp-content\themes\sparrow\functions.php:41) in C:\OSPanel\domains\ancores.com\wp-admin\includes\misc.php on line 1196

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at C:\OSPanel\domains\ancores.com\wp-content\themes\sparrow\functions.php:41) in C:\OSPanel\domains\ancores.com\wp-includes\pluggable.php on line 1251

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at C:\OSPanel\domains\ancores.com\wp-content\themes\sparrow\functions.php:41) in C:\OSPanel\domains\ancores.com\wp-includes\pluggable.php on line 1254

Подскажите пожалуйста, что может быть не так? Перечитал много форумов, с файлов "**Wp-config**" вроде всё нормально.

Заранее спасибо.

Comment: `\themes\sparrow\functions.php:41` что в этой строке?

Comment: А тему то обновили?

Comment: @Dantessss темы была создана мной, разве ее нужно как-то обновлять?

Comment: @InDevX там пустая строка (не знаю как вставить код, чтобы показать)

Comment: @ancores создана вами, значит вам ее и обновлять под новую версию wp. Код вставте, обновив вопрос

Comment: @Dantessss спасибо Вам за ответ, но я устранил проблему. Оказалось нужно было просто убрать пустые строки у файле functions.php

Comment: @InDevX спасибо Вам за ответ, но я устранил проблему. Оказалось нужно было просто убрать пустые строки у файле functions.php

Comment: @ancores естественно. Пустая строка - вывод на экран. После вывода на экран невозможно поставить headers - это ограничение протокола http